# Why won't all my boolean types run and give separate results?

Tags: java

When you run the code it only tells you the you are under weight every time, even when the BMI is not under weight.

```
public class BMI_Calc 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This program computes your BMI");
        System.out.print("What is first your name? ");
        String name  = sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
        double weight = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter your height in inches: ");
        double height = sc.nextDouble();
        double new_weight = weight*703;
        double new_height = height * height;
        double bmi = new_weight/new_height;
        boolean isUnderweight;
        boolean isNormalweight;
        boolean isOverweight;
        boolean isObese;

        System.out.println("Dear " + name + ", your BMI is " + bmi +" and you are under weight.");
        bmi = sc.nextDouble();
        isUnderweight = (bmi<=18.5);

        System.out.println("Dear " + name + " your BMI is " + bmi +" and you are normal weight.");
        bmi = sc.nextDouble();
        isNormalweight = (bmi>18.5&&bmi<24.9);

        System.out.println("Dear " + name + " your BMI is " + bmi +" and you are over weight.");
        bmi = sc.nextDouble();
        isOverweight = (bmi>24.9&&bmi<29.9);

        System.out.println("Dear " + name + " your BMI is " + bmi +" and you are obese.");
        bmi = sc.nextDouble();
        isObese = (bmi>=30.0);

        sc.close();

    }
```

Why won't all my boolean types run and give separate results?

Can anyone help solve this problem?

Comment: You're not skipping the line separator. You need to add `Scanner#nextLine` before trying to read user input.

Comment: That's because you have coded it that way. You don't have any conditions in your code, so your first print statement always gets executed - and then you ask the user for input and overwrite the calculated BMI value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is stuck at underweight is because you asked for input after that. Asking for input stops the program until you enter input. Try to do this code instead:

```
 public class BMI_Calc.java
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("This program computes your BMI");
            System.out.print("What is first your name? ");
            String name  = sc.next();
            System.out.print("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
            double weight = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter your height in inches: ");
            double height = sc.nextDouble();
            double new_weight = weight*703;
            double new_height = height * height;
            double bmi = new_weight/new_height;
            boolean isUnderweight = (bmi<=18.5);
            boolean isNormalweight = (bmi>18.5&&bmi<24.9);
            boolean isOverweight = (bmi>24.9&&bmi<29.9);
            boolean isObese = (bmi>=30.0);

            if(isUnderweight){
                System.out.println("Dear " + name + ", your BMI is " + bmi +" and you are under weight.");
            }else if(isNormalweight){
                System.out.println("Dear " + name + " your BMI is " + bmi +" and you are normal weight.");
            }else if(isOverweight){
                System.out.println("Dear " + name + " your BMI is " + bmi +" and you are over weight.");
            }else if(isObese){
                System.out.println("Dear " + name + " your BMI is " + bmi +" and you are obese.");
            }

            sc.close();

        }
```

Comment: How would I make BMI decimal places round up?